# CSR generated by keytool is not acceptable by Network Solutions

Tags: ssl, openssl, tomcat7, ssl-certificate, keytool

When submitting CSR on the esteemed site `Network Solutions` I get an error message `The CSR provided uses an unsupported signature algorithm. Supported algorithms are: md5withrsa, sha1withrsa, oid 1.2.840.113549.1.1.4, oid 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5`. The command I am using is below and not sure why there are not accepting it when this is exactly what they have listed on [their site](http://www.networksolutions.com/support/csr-for-java-based-webservers-such-as-tomcat-using-keytool/) and on `Apache Tomcat` site

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -keystore domain_keystore.jks -keysize 2048
```

Followed by the command to generate `CSR`

```
keytool -certreq -alias tomcat -file domain_keystore.csr -keystore domain_keystore.jks
```

When I use `openssl` to generate key it gets accepted by `Network Solutions`. But some how I cannot get it to run with tomcat :(

```
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout www_website_com.key -out www_website_com.csr
```

Exhausted and need help in installing thrid party certificate on Mac + Tomcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-sigalg` option to specify a signature algorithm to use with `keytool -certreq`.

```
keytool -certreq -sigalg sha1withrsa -alias tomcat -file domain_keystore.csr -keystore domain_keystore.jks
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I have submitted new request on `Network Solutions` site. Hope it works out. Will update if I run into some issue. Thanks.